# ajax datatable returns "[object Object]" instead of datetime format

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datetime, crud

I want to display from my database a timestamp data type in ajax datatable.

But when the data table loads it shows "[object Object]" instead of a datetime format.

Could there be anything I need to add?

Here is my ajax code:

```
function search() {
        $('#data-table').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                "url": "{{ route('cust_continfo_data_table') }}",
                "dataType": "json",
                "type": "POST",
                "data":{ _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}" }
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                { "white-space": 'nowrap', "targets": 4 },
                { "overflow": 'hidden', "targets": 4 },
                { "max-width": '150px', "targets": 4 },
            ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "receipt_date" },
                { "data": "info_division_name" },
                { "data": "contact_status" },
                { "data": "note" },
                { "data": "created_at" },
                { "data": "updated_at" }
            ],
            "pageLength": 10,
            "searching": false,
            "info": false,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "oLanguage": {
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "{{ trans('pagination.previous') }}",
                    "sNext": "{{ trans('pagination.next') }}",
                },
                "sEmptyTable": "{{ trans('data-table.empty_table') }}",
                "sProcessing": "{{ trans('data-table.processing') }}",
            },
        });
    }
```

`created_at` and `updated_at` are the timestamp data type that shows [object Object].

How can make it in datetime format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a valid format on controller side, where you are creating created_at and updated_at value, like this:-

```
$createdAt = 2018-01-23;

'created_at' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($createdAt))
```